# Where is docker-ee-selinux-17.06.1.ee.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm

Tags: docker, docker-engine

Docker has just released a 17.06 version of docker-ee. But there is no selinux rpm in trial packages `/rhel/7.3/x86_64/stable-17.06/Packages/`, and `yum install docker-ee-17.06.1.ee.1-1.el7.rhel.x86_64.rpm` failed because of selinux needed.

Anybody knows where to find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

docker-ee 17.06 uses container-selinux, so `yum install container-selinux-2.19-2.1.el7.noarch.rpm`.